# Wildcard SSL Certificate registration with multi-level subdomains

Tags: ssl, dns, subdomain

My client owns "domain.com". We need to give various applications friendly names for internal and external access. The applications are WCF web services and MVC web applications with varying levels of authentication (Windows auth within and across AD domains and plain text authentication). It looks a little like this:

**UAT Environment**

- service1.uat.services.domain.com
- service2.uat.services.domain.com
- service3.uat.services.domain.com
- service4.uat.services.domain.com
- application1.uat.apps.domain.com
- application2.uat.apps.domain.com

**Production Environment**

- service1.services.domain.com
- service2.services.domain.com
- service3.services.domain.com
- service4.services.domain.com
- application1.apps.domain.com
- application2.apps.domain.com

We're likely to have a LOT more sub domains, and everything needs to be secured with SSL.

We've changed our minds on how to configure this a number of times, but now we've hit a possible restriction. We thought a wildcard SSL certificate might work, but apparently they only work to a single level of subdomain i.e. *.services.domain.com.

Because of budget, we'd like to register a single wildcard SSL certificate and apply it to multiple servers (belonging to multiple AD Domains, and also a few servers in our DMZ).

This morning I had an idea, but I don't know enough about this stuff to make a definite decision. Do any of you foresee any restrictions on using the following naming convention instead of the above?

- service1-uat-services.domain.com
- service2-uat-services.domain.com
- service3-uat-services.domain.com
- service4-uat-services.domain.com
- application1-uat-apps.domain.com
- application2-uat-apps.domain.com
- service1-services.domain.com
- service2-services.domain.com
- service3-services.domain.com
- service4-services.domain.com
- application1-apps.domain.com
- application2-apps.domain.com

That way, we can register a wildcard for *.domain.com and use a single level subdomain for each application / service, but still allow us to keep everything logically separate. Are there any technical issues anyone can identify using this set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem with that.